# Strange behaviour of full outer join in Oracle - how it could be explained?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have noticed a strange behaviour of FULL OUTER JOIN in Oracle 11. I was joining tables from HR schema, particularily EMPLOYEES and DEPARTMENTS.

For example, the following query returns 123 rows:

```
    SELECT * FROM employees e
    FULL JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
```

However, what is tricky to understand - when I put a set of particular columns in the select clause, the query will return 122 rows (a missing row is for an employee which has no department assigned - the one which is additionally returned with left join in comparison to inner join):

```
    SELECT first_name, last_name, department_name FROM employees e
    FULL JOIN departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id
```

Even when I count the rows it returns 122 (`COUNT(*)`)!!! WHAT IS GOING ON? What is the difference between `SELECT *` and `SELECT COUNT(*)`?

The explain plan for `SELECT * ...` :

```
SELECT STATEMENT                                      122
  VIEW                 VW_FOJ_0                       122
    HASH JOIN                          FULL OUTER     122
      Access Predicates
        E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID
      TABLE ACCESS     DEPARTMENTS     FULL            27
      TABLE ACCESS     EMPLOYEES       FULL           107
```

and for `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` :

```
SELECT STATEMENT                                             1
  SORT                                     AGGREGATE         1
    VIEW               VW_FOJ_0                            122
      HASH JOIN                            FULL OUTER      122
        Access Predicates
          E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID
        INDEX          DEPT_ID_PK          FAST FULL SCAN   27
        INDEX          EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX   FAST FULL SCAN  107
```

Comment: What happens if you use the `union` for those columns ? do get something different when using `union all` ? what do get if you count with `group by first_name, last_name, department_name `?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM employees e FULL JOIN departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id` returns 123 rows and `SELECT count(*) FROM employees e FULL JOIN departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id` returns 122 rows?

Comment: Yes, exactly - that's why I've posted this question.

Comment: can you post the explain plans for these queryes? Should be different.

Comment: Even cardinality in the first plan is strange - it is 122, but the query returns 123 rows.

Comment: The cardinality is an approximation if you've obtained the plan with  autotrace or DBMS_XPLAN. The actual cardinality can be found in the SQL trace file.

Comment: I'll edit your question to be more precise, i'll remove the query with left and right join because it does not help with anything.

Comment: Are you really using `count(*)` or maybe something like `count(empno)`?

Comment: Yes, it is really `count(*)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The optimizer should not be choosing to use the index on EMP.DEPT_ID in the second query, since it can have NULL values.  This is what's causing it to exclude one row from the results.

The only non-bug explanation I can think of at the moment is that you have somehow created constraints in DISABLE RELY mode so that the optimizer thinks that the field cannot contain NULLs.  In this case it would be correct to use the index given the incorrect information in the constraints.  However, it seems the RELY option is not available for NOT NULL constraints, so I don't see how this could be the problem.  Nonetheless, take a careful look at all constraints on the tables.

That aside, there are a surprising number of bugs on Oracle's site regarding wrong results from full outer joins.  You might be hitting one of them.  In quite a few of these cases, the workaround is to disable "native" full outer joins, which you can do for your current session with this statement:

```
alter session set "_optimizer_native_full_outer_join"=off;
```

Comment: +1: it looks like the most plausible explanation. It would be interesting to know the DB version.

Answer (score 1):

(Can't write this in a comment)

The results are conformed to execution plans.

The count(*) execution plan uses the index EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX which contains all dept_ids from employess table. But indexes does not contain nulls. So, this execution plan will "lose" the emps with null department_id.

However, should be explained why Oracle choose this execution plan in case of

```
select first_name, last_name, department_name
```

and

```
select count(*)
```

in opposition to

```
select *
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. However this is a kind of inconsistency in my opinion. Full outer join does not work as it should in all cases except for selecting *.

Comment: @luckyjaca Can you do more tests with `select emp_id`, `select first_name`, `select e.department_id`, `select d.department_id`, `select d.department_name`, etc?

Comment: heh... I've done the tests as you suggested. Nevertheless, all of them returned 122 rows - the only way to get 123 rows is selecting all columns by asterix. However, finally I've managed to return 123 rows by using hint: `/*+ no_index(e) */`. It is enough to make all the queries work - either `COUNT(*)` or `first_name, last_name, department_name`.

Comment: that's really strange. Hints should not affect the results.

Comment: Yes, I know. One more thing according to what you wrote - if you look at the last row on the second execution plan, where EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX is accessed, it says that cardinality is 107 - it means that all of the employees are indexed - even the one with a null value in the indexed column.

Comment: how did you changed the HR schema? DDL, DML... Do you have disabled FKs? not null on department id? etc? If you have not null on department_id, it can use index.

Comment: Following up on Florin's last comment -- suggest you show us all the constraints that exist on these two tables.  Since it is possible for EMP.DEPT_ID to be NULL, the optimizer should not be choosing to use the index on that field.

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't change the HR schema. There is a single employee which have NULL value in department_id column. There are also departments which do not have any employee assigned. When I execute left join, I get all employees and the execution of right join returns all departments. I expect that full join returns all employees and all departments.