# Oracle 11g Release 1 vs. 2 — different behavior of LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, left-join

I found this after upgrading from Oracle 11g Release 1 to Release 2.

The best I can summarize it right now is that a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` against a query with a constant "fake" column and a `WHERE` clause generates different results in the two Oracle RELEASES.  In Release 2, the "fake" column shows up in the unmatched rows:

```
TEST1      TEST2
=====      =====
A B        A B 
- ---      - ---
1 bar      1 hello
2 baz

> SELECT * FROM test1 LEFT OUTER JOIN test2 ON test1.a = test2.a;
  A B   A_1 B_1
  - --- --- -----
  1 bar   1 hello
  2 baz
```

So far, so good.  all of the above works the same on Rel. 1 and 2.  Now, add a 'fake' constant column X, and things work as expected:

```
> SELECT * 
    FROM test1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT test2.*, 'X' AS X 
                       FROM test2) test3 
      ON test1.a = test3.a;

  A B   A_1 B_1   X
  - --- --- ----- -
  1 bar   1 hello X
  2 baz
```

Now, add a `WHERE` clause on the first table and get **different** results:

```
> SELECT * 
    FROM test1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT test2.*, 'X' AS X 
                       FROM  test2) test3 
      ON test1.a = test3.a
   WHERE test1.b LIKE 'ba%';

  Release 11.1.0.7.0        Release 11.2.0.2.0    
  ==================        ==================
  A B   A_1 B_1   X         A B   A_1 B_1   X
  - --- --- ----- -         - --- --- ----- -
  1 bar   1 hello X         1 bar   1 hello X
  2 baz                     2 baz           X  <--- WHAT'S THIS?!
```

Further puzzlement: if the WHERE condition is numeric (e.g., `WHERE test1.a < 5`, the results are the same!

**UPDATE (to clarify my actual question):**
What I am doing wrong?  Is my final query somehow invoking an undefined behavior making it OK for Oracle to change what's returned from one release to the next?  If not, is this an Oracle bug?

Comment: If that's a question, it's not really clear.

Comment: @dystroy, I've added an update, trying to make my question explicit.

Comment: This level of detail might be better suited to the DBA stackexchange.

Comment: However, I would only expect the behavior in 11.1.0.7.

Comment: @pst, yes, the 11.2 behavior seems wrong (Oracle bug, **really**?)

Comment: Both versions generate the same plan (I hope)?

Comment: @pst, the plans are the save except CPU Cost (5M in the older release, 2M in the newer one).  Could some optimization be involved here and breaking things?

Comment: Doesn't seem to happen in 11.2.0.3 (RHEL 64-bit), so presumably a bug.

Comment: There are quite a few bug fixes between 11.2.0.2 and 11.2.0.3 in regards to outer joins, specifically producing errors or incorrect results. Looks like you've hit one of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am going to answer my own question, namely: "Am I doing something wrong or is this an Oracle bug?" with **This is an Oracle bug**.

I leave it up to you to navigate the insanity known as *support.oracle.com*, but, as pointed out by @AdamHawkes, this bug is *probably* addressed in a recent Oracle patch set.  A couple of bugs in the release notes to 11.2.0.3 seem similar to my problem, though not exactly the same.

I'll try to come back here and update the answer when I get the latest patches applied (I am in an environment where I am not in control of this).

Answer (score 0):

Just linking in some related posts for other readers..

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1113096

[Strange behaviour of full outer join in Oracle - how it could be explained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717697/strange-behaviour-of-full-outer-join-in-oracle-how-it-could-be-explained)

Mainly suggests altering the session to turn off specific optimizations. 
alter session set "_optimizer_join_elimination_enabled" = false;
alter session set "_optimizer_native_full_outer_join"=off;

I would rather they had automated tests that proved simple things worked and didn't just introduce these bugs in the first place.